# Octobercms: how to translate flash messages?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, october-form-controller

I use `translate.rainlab` plugin for localization, but not sure how to translate flash messages for ajax form.

```
function onMailSend() {
    Mail::sendTo('name@example.com', 'contact.form', post());
    Flash::success('Message has been sent');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stick with using the Translate plugin's features, no need to use another translation mechanism.

```
use RainLab\Translate\Models\Message;

function onMailSend() {
    Mail::sendTo('name@example.com', 'contact.form', post());
    Flash::success(Message::trans('Message has been sent'));
}
```

This assumes that "Message has been sent" is the string in the default locale.

Comment: I like your straightforward solution. However, a small typo has crept in. Another double point is missing `Message::trans`.

Comment: Thanks @creg, fixed the typos.

Answer (score 2):

translate plugin is used for translating **content** front-end side, but for translating messages within code, its good idea to use locale lang messages.

suppose this is your site : http://octdev.local.com/demo/ajax (default lang is set to en)

then you can create plugin and within `lang/en/lang.php` file you can define translation messages

> en lang file will be there and default content will be look like this

```
// lang/en/lang.php
<?php return [
    'plugin' => [
        'name' => 'TestPlugin',
        'description' => ''
    ]
];
```

you can access this messages any where

```
\Flash::success(\Lang::get('hardiksatasiya.testplugin::lang.plugin.name'));
```

> hardiksatasiya.testplugin => `plugin auther name` . `pluginname`
>
> lang.plugin.name => worked like array `lang` stands for file name (language) then get `plugin array` then its key `name` so in our case it will out put **TestPlugin**

now you can use new url : **http://octdev.local.com/de/demo/ajax** its in **de**

so you can create new lang file in your plugin directory `lang/de/lang.php` and put same above php code with translated messages

```
// lang/de/lang.php
<?php return [
    'plugin' => [
        'name' => 'TestPlugin In de',
        'description' => ''
    ]
];
```

and it will work. if you need whole document you can use this 
reference : https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/localization

**update**
if you think i only needed to do in one place you can do something like this  (but not preferred way)

```
$locale = \Lang::getLocale();
switch($locale) {
  case 'en':
     \Flash::success('Message has been sent - EN');
     break;
  case 'de':
     \Flash::success('Message has been sent - DE');
     break;
  default:
     \Flash::success('Message has been sent - default');
}
```

Comment: So, in any way, I have to create a new separate plugin just to translate couple of messages and there's no simpler native way to do it, correct?

Comment: If this is the only message you want to translate you can do it manually.
\Lang::getLocale() will return you selected locale `de` or `en` now you can put switch..case  or if else , and assign your flash message (added updated block in answer just check it once)

Comment: yeah, that will do it. Thank you so much for such an informative answer.